# Agregar header (usernametoken) a web reference C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice, soap

Buenas noches,

Agregue un servicio web como web reference, y necesito crear la cabecera con la autenticacion (Password y username), Se hacerlo cuando agrego un Service Reference, pero con web reference no.
Alguien puede ayudarme, please?.

he leido sobre Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.Tokens  pero no se si puedo hacerlo con visual studio 2013, ps no lo he logrado agregar.

Estoy trabajando con Visual Studio 2013 C#

Gracias, Buenas noches.

Comment: ¿Te sirvió de algo la respuesta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tu servicio web está configurado para trabajar con autentificación básica. Con este tipo de autentificación, el cliente (es decir, tu programa) le pasa las credenciales al webservice, por ejemplo:

```
localhost.Service1 webService = new localhost.Service1();
System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential()
{
    Domain = "tu-dominio",
    UserName = "tu-usuario",
    Password = "tu-password"
};
webService.Credentials = credentials;
string result = webService.HelloWorld();
```